# Android toggle button save state custom listview

Tags: java, android, android-togglebutton

Hello friend i am new in android i want to know how to save `ToggleButton` state in custom `ArrayAdapter` i create custom `ListView` with help of `ArrayAdapter`  now i want how save its state in `Adapter` here is my code  pleae explain what logic used to achieve this goal i am on beginner level don't how to achieve this goal?

```java
package bible.swordof.God;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable;
import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.util.ColorGenerator;
import com.hitomi.cmlibrary.CircleMenu;
import com.hitomi.cmlibrary.OnMenuSelectedListener;
import com.hitomi.cmlibrary.OnMenuStatusChangeListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
import static android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_NONE;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.V;
import static android.support.constraint.Constraints.TAG;
import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext;
import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;

public class FullverseAdopter extends ArrayAdapter < String > {
    private ALLVERSE activity;

    private List < String > versenumber;
    private List < String > verseid;
    private List < String > verselist;
    private List < String > refernce;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private boolean save;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";


    //check for availabe language
    int result;


    public FullverseAdopter(ALLVERSE context, int resource, List < String > versenumber, List < String > verselist, List < String > refernce, List < String > verseid) {
        super(context, resource, versenumber);
        this.activity = context;
        this.versenumber = versenumber;
        this.verselist = verselist;
        this.refernce = refernce;
        this.verseid = verseid;



    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return versenumber.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return versenumber.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.versedisplayrow, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder

            holder.versenumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.versenumber);
            holder.verselist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.verse);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.versenumber.setText(versenumber.get(position));
        holder.verselist.setText(verselist.get(position));

        //share verse
        holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toasty.info(activity, "Sharing a verse.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, refernce.get(position) + ":" + versenumber.get(position) + '\n' + verselist.get(position));
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                activity.startActivity(sendIntent);

            }
        });


        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(activity, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {

                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "YOUR DEVICE NOT SUPPORTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });




        //My toggle button 
        holder.bookmark.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {


                } else {

                }
            }
        });
        //mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        //mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        //ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        //contentValues.put("id",verseid.get(position));
        //contentValues.put("bookname",refernce.get(position));
        //contentValues.put("versenumber",versenumber.get(position));
        //contentValues.put("verse",verselist.get(position));
        //long check=mDb.insert("favourite",null,contentValues);

        //Log.d("MY_TAG","DB IS NOW "+check);

        //Toasty.success(activity, "Added in favouite"+check, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

        holder.speakverse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(activity, "I AM CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Language not supported or Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {


                    textToSpeech.speak(verselist.get(position), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                }
            }
        });


        /* holder.removebookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
               mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

              // long delete= mDb.delete("favourite","id=?",new String[]{verseid.get(position)});




               //Toasty.error(activity, "Remove in favouite"+delete, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
            }
        });*/


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private ToggleButton favourite;
        private TextView versenumber;
        private TextView verselist;
        private CircleMenu circleMenu;
        private ImageView share;

        //toggle button
        public ToggleButton bookmark;

        private boolean defaultvalue;

        private ALLVERSE activity;
        private ImageView speakverse;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            versenumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.versenumber);
            verselist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.verse);
            share = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.share);
            bookmark = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.adbookmark);
            speakverse = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.speakverse);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @omer Erden tell me?

Comment: please tell me how to save state check my code?

Comment: You already approved an answer, you shouldn't approve answer if it doesn't solve your problem. And please read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) before asking questions because with minimal content you can get more attention to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally an adapter is an object to adapt a particular dataset to render a view within a listview. So you should have a data structure (class object) for every row visible in that list view and put it in an array list. Based on the position in getView method, retrieve the data for the row and initialize views from this data. Now this data set can be saved on server or in local memory in any format preferably in JSON and can be retrieved back in future.